# Remove id from html to reuse code

Tags: html, css, class, carousel

I am trying to reuse this image slider in multiple places on my website but because of the ids I cannot do this.

I got this code from an old code pen but it is a little more complex than I am use to so I am wondering if anyone can help me with this.

This is the html :

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
.slides * {
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-  touch-callout: none;
}
.slides {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}
.slides input {
 display: none;
}
.slide-container {
 display: block;
}
.slide {
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: all .7s slide;
}
.slide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.nav label {
 width: 50px;
 height: 100%;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 9;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: opacity .2s;
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 75pt;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 380px;
 font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px  rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
.slide:hover + .nav label {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav label:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.nav .next {
 right: 0;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .slide {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
 display: block;
}
.nav-dots {
 width: 100%;
 bottom: -20px;
 left: 26%;
 height: 11px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
.nav-dots .nav-dot {
 top: -5px;
 width: 5px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0  4px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.6);
}
.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.8);
}
input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1, input#img-2:checked ~  .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,  input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3, input#img-4:checked ~  .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,  input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5, input#img-6:checked ~  .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Mate</h3>
    <ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
     </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-dots">
        <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
        <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
        <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

majority of css is style I know but I feel it is necessary to include for context.

Comment: show us your working codes ? create a fiddle or code pen

Comment: could you add the css?

Comment: @JishnuVS this is the code pen link : https://codepen.io/AMKohn/pen/EKJHf

Comment: In this case use label for and label for need an ID.

Comment: If you remove the id, the labels won't work, so why don't give different id's when using it multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Use the code as-is, with the inputs and label-fors.

The reason you couldn't get it to work probably is that your ids didn't match. If you change the id on an input, you must update the label for accordingly (in each case).

Each image in this codepen has an input id associated  with it, so it's important that if you change the id that you also update the label; then the code should will work

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

html,
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit- touch-callout: none;
}

.slides {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all .7s slide;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 75pt;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 380px;
  font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover+.nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dots {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 26%;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
  top: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.8);
}

.nav label:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}

.nav-dots {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 9px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
  top: -5px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked~.nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h3>Mate</h3>
  <ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/babytiger.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/snowdrops.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daffodils1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-dots">
      <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
      <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
      <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

[Sample fiddle with your css applied](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/su8odzsh/2/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I see the code you put on fiddle but when I copy the <ul> to make two different sliders (and I change the ids) I still cant see both sliders at one time

Comment: @Cameron sorry I only saw your comment now. I think you may be making a mistake in the previous and next, the previous in the first slide will be the last id of the group and the 'next' of the first slide will be slide 2. Likewise the 'previous' of the last slide will be the id of the second to last and the 'next' of the last slide is the id of the first of the group. Give that a whirl and see how you go. If no joy, post a fiddle. Good you remembered to make fresh ids for the second slider, as ids can only be used once and this would've confused things.